# passing command line arguments in coded ui tests

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to pass command line arguments in coded ui test ? in normal C# programs we just pass the arguments along with the exe file eg: filename.exe "2" "7" in command prompt.

but can something like this be done in coded ui tests?

Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/04/16/more-on-data-driving-coded-ui-tests.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can do that. `CodedUi` tests are executed through command line through `MSTest` which does not support it. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to see the available command-line options of `MSTest`.

However, you can create another `Project` (e.g. console application) to achieve that. The second project has a reference to your `CodedUI Project`. Then pass the parameters through the .exe file of this Project which calls the appropriate `CodedUI Test Method`. But I think that this will not work like `MSTest` does (it will not create Test Results).